# migrate web application to enterprise application

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, inject

I had a web application where I injected a dao class in my ejb class (`@Stateless`) and it worked fine but I needed to migrate this web application for enterprise application and `@Inject` didn't work more:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [AsteriskDAO] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private br.com.vsdialer.facade.AsteriskFacade.asteriskDao]
```

The code:

```
@Stateless
public class AsteriskFacade extends GenericFacade<Asterisk> implements AsteriskFacadeLocal, AsteriskFacadeRemote{

    @Inject
    private AsteriskDAO asteriskDao;

    @Override
    @PostConstruct
    protected void inicializar() {
        setDao(asteriskDao);
    }
}

public class AsteriskDAO extends GenericDAO<Asterisk>{

}
```

Comment: I'm using jee 6, jboss eap 6.1

Comment: EJB in web app is not the same that EJB in JEE app, the EJB in JEE behavior is diferent.

Answer (score 0):

The error means, that the CDI container can't find the component which you want to inject.

It may be the case that the `beans.xml` is not found since your deployment artefact changed. Check the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html) for where to place it.

Comment: it's true, I forgot to put beans.xml file in META-INF of EJB Project. thanks

Comment: @AlissonVieira: Then feel free to accept the answer ;-)